# Getting Wireless driver

Tags: wireless

I've been trying to get a ubuntu linux distro working on my computer the past day or two, and have everything working fine, except for my wireless card. I used the command

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

and the response I got was

```
04:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)
```

Anyone know why I'm fine with Wired connections, but Wireless doesn't even find my network?

Comment: Are you sure that you need the drivers? Edit the question and add the output of `nm-cli`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Unfortunetely, this has not worked, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your wireless card is turned off in software even though it's got power. Go into the control panel and look for an On/Off switch graphic and make sure it's set to "On". I had the same problem with my laptop and that was the solution.

Comment: That wasn't it either, but thanks for the help. I managed to find the issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx in case anyone else every has the same issue :)